# Kentico 11 MFA in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico, multi-factor-authentication

We are looking to utilize Multi Factor Authentication in a custom MVC App which connects to Kentico. I want to ensure i'm getting the right direction, is this the starting point: https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/configuring-multi-factor-authentication#Configuringmulti-factorauthentication-Customizingmulti-factorauthentication

can we leverage the Kentico API to utilize the MFA functionality or do we have to write our own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, the fact that Kentico MVC memebership is built on a good part on ASP.NET Identity it seems easier, to actually implement this with [NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity).

Kentico MVC package is available on [github](https://github.com/Kentico/Mvc/tree/6895fca35509c9d0a2a224c2a4a8df7a8dbbc714/src/Kentico.Membership) for review. Package implements a [user store](https://github.com/Kentico/Mvc/blob/6895fca35509c9d0a2a224c2a4a8df7a8dbbc714/src/Kentico.Membership/UserStore.cs) in which Kentico (application) users are loaded per request and this store manages their authentication.

Store implements IUserTwoFactorStore which means store can be used with above idenity for multi factor authentication. It also has a retrieval method:

GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync

while SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync throws NotImplemented exception. Meaning you can have users stored and managed within Kentico backend and you can enable MF authentication for them via administration interface, while you can use .NET methods to have MF authentication on MVC site.

It seems easier than to actually reference Kentico DLLs for MF authentication in MVC project.